# How use the coroutine within extend function in the latest kotlin-couroutine

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kotlin-coroutines

In the example: [kotlin-examples/coroutines/src/main/kotlin/movierating/App.kt](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/kotlin-examples/coroutines/src/main/kotlin/movierating/App.kt)
There is the flowing code:

```
    fun Route.coroutineHandler(fn: suspend (RoutingContext) -> Unit) {
    handler { ctx ->
      launch(ctx.vertx().dispatcher()) {
        try {
          fn(ctx)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
          ctx.fail(e)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In the latest kotlin-coroutine,to invoke launch must depend on a CoroutineScope;
So the launch can't be invoked in the extend function Route.coroutineHandler() ;

If always use GlobalScope.launch() to start couroutine,how manage the life-cycle properly?

So I use the flowing method:

```
interface SuspendHandler<E>: Handler<E>,CoroutineScope {
    override fun handle(event: E) {
        launch {
            suspendHandle(event)
        }
    }

    suspend fun suspendHandle(event: E)
}

fun <E> vertxSuspendHandler(vertx: Vertx = getDefaultVertx(),
                            block:suspend CoroutineScope.(E)->Unit): SuspendHandler<E>{
    return object: SuspendHandler<E> {
        override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
            get() = vertx.dispatcher()

        override suspend fun suspendHandle(event: E) {
            block(event)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how use extend function in the latest coroutine api;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding the following extension:

```kotlin
fun Route.suspendHandler(requestHandler: suspend (RoutingContext) -> Unit) {
  handler { ctx ->
    CoroutineScope(ctx.vertx().dispatcher()).launch {
      requestHandler(ctx)
    }.invokeOnCompletion {
      it?.run { ctx.fail(it) }
    }
  }
}
```

You can place this extension anywhere in the code.